# Take backup and delete it after 6 hours

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to make a bash script that takes a backup of file `abc.txt` and deletes this backup 6 hours after creating it.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: This is a really odd back-up scheme. Usually you don't *delete* back-ups; you *replace* them with more recent back-ups. That sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly why you want to do this? **Note to close voters: Stop being silly, this is abundantly clear what he wants to do. Just because what he wants to do is strange does not make it unclear what he is asking.**

Comment: crontab maybe?
`* * 12 cp /path/to/abc.txt /path/to/backup \\
* * 18 rm /path/to/backup` That would create a backup at 1200 and delete it at 1800 every day

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure what is the use case but you could simply do:

```
cp abc.txt abc.txt.bak && sleep $((60 * 60 * 6)) && rm abc.txt.bak
```

- `&&` is short-circuit evaluation operator, the command after it will only be run if the preceding one exits with exit status 0
- `cp abc.txt abc.txt.bak` makes a backup of `abc.txt` with a `.bak` extension i.e. the backup is named `abc.txt.bak` (modify this to meet your need)
- `sleep $((60 * 60 * 6))` sleeps for 6 hours i.e. 21600 seconds
- `rm abc.txt.bak` removes the backup after the slept time

---

You can leverage brace expansion for brevity, if you want:

```
cp abc.txt{,.bak} && sleep $((60 * 60 * 6)) && rm abc.txt.bak
```

---

Or as (GNU) `sleep` supports `h` suffix for indicating hours (thanks @muru for the reminder):

```
cp abc.txt{,.bak} && sleep 6h && rm abc.txt.bak
```

Comment: GNU sleep can do `sleep 6h`